# Remove Azure devops Connection From Solution

Tags: azure-devops

I have pushed my project to azure devops, now i need to give this solution file to some developers for security testing. Donot want to add them in azure devops.

I want to just give them the whole solution file so they can do their testing. How do I remove the references of azuredevops and give it to them?

I still want to continue working on that project in azure devops though.. whats the best way to do this?